# C# VSTO Outlook Addin count recipients .CC, .TO, .BCC separately

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, mailitem

In my Outlook Addin I need to add conditions for creating a new email. There can be only one recipient in the field `.TO`.

Adding a recipinets to fields `.CC`, `BCC` is not allowed.

condition for `(inspectorMailItem.Recipients.Count != 1)` work and for `(inspectorMailItem.Attachments.Count == 0)` works too.

But why cant do same for `(inspectorMailItem.CC.Count != 0)` ?

Error `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'`

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = new 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Inspector inspector = application.ActiveInspector();

        if (inspector.CurrentItem is MailItem inspectorMailItem)
        {
            String Subject = inspectorMailItem.Subject;
            String EmailAddress = inspectorMailItem.To;

            if (inspectorMailItem.Recipients.Count != 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("More then one recipient.");
            }

            else if (inspectorMailItem.CC.Count != 0)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Recipient in CC not allowed.");    
            }

            else if (inspectorMailItem.Bcc.Count != 0)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Recipient in Bcc not allowed.");    
            }

            else if (inspectorMailItem.Attachments.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No attachment.");
            }
            
            else
            {
              //
            }
```

UPDATE

I replace `count` to `length`:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = new 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Inspector inspector = application.ActiveInspector();

        if (inspector.CurrentItem is MailItem inspectorMailItem)
        {
            String Subject = inspectorMailItem.Subject;
            String EmailAddress = inspectorMailItem.To;

            if (inspectorMailItem.Recipients.Count != 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("More then one recipient.");
            }

            else if (inspectorMailItem.CC.Length != 0)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Recipient in CC not allowed.");    
            }

            else if (inspectorMailItem.Bcc.Length != 0)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Recipient in Bcc not allowed.");    
            }

            else if (inspectorMailItem.Attachments.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No attachment.");
            }
            
            else
            {
              //
            }
```

It works but when `.To` is blank and `.CC` is blank, only `BCC` filled have this error : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

in details problem is this line
`else if (inspectorMailItem.CC.Length != 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the `MailItem.Recipients` collection and check the `Recipient.Type` property (`olTo` / `olCC` / `olBCC`).

Answer (score 0):

working solution:

```
     Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
     MailItem inspectorMailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;

     String Subject = inspectorMailItem.Subject;
     String EmailAddress = inspectorMailItem.To;

     if (inspectorMailItem.Recipients.Count != 1)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("More then one recipient.");

                this.Hide();
            }

            else if ((inspectorMailItem.CC != null) || (inspectorMailItem.BCC != null))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("CC or BCC not allowed");

                this.Hide();
            }

            else if (inspectorMailItem.Attachments.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Missing attachment");

                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                //
            }
```